# Trip to Estonia Tallinn from Greece

Tags: greece, tallinn, estonia

Which is the best way to travel from Greece to Estonia Tallinn?
There isn't any direct flight,the intermediate stops I found was Frankfurt and Moscow (you have to wait one day).
Are there any places you have to visit?
Is it easy to visit neighboring countries and how?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indeed Estonia has very few directs flights from anywhere and the situation has gone worse over the last couple of years. But there are a few alternatives which can make everything more fun, if you have time to travel.

- Fly to **Riga**, enjoy this great city for a day or two, take a bus to Tallinn.
  The trip takes about 4 hours and costs between 13 and 30€, [see schedule](http://www.luxexpress.eu/en/timetable).
- Fly to **Helsinki**, dito, take a ferry to Tallinn, to my knowledge there aren't any other two capital cities connected by water by such a close distance.
  The trip takes between 2 and 4 hours, depending on the ferry type, prices start from 50€. Just google 'Helsinki Tallinn ferry' to find the different lines, I recommend [Silja Line](http://www.tallinksilja.com/en/schedules/helTal/default.htm) because they're fast and dock in conventient places.
- Fly to St. Petersburg or Moscow, dito, take a train to Tallinn.

For finding flights, as Karlson wrote, SkyScanner is your best friend. The chances that somebody will be able to tell you anything SkyScanner doesn't know, are very slim.

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple options available without the long layover from [SkyScanner](http://www.skyscanner.com/flights/ath/tll/130302/130309/airfares-from-athens-international-to-tallinn-in-march-2013.html) and [Rome2Rio](http://www.rome2rio.com/s/Athens/Tallinn) and those with long layovers in Moscow or Munich.

But I am sure that you can find something with a stopovers at other places [St. Petersburg, Russia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saint_petersburg) and then just take a train from there.

Comment: I see you recommend Russia,do you know if I need passport in order to travel there;

Comment: There are a few exceptions, but on the whole you normally need a passport to visit other countries!

Comment: @Gagravarr by exceptions you mean?For instance let's say I fly to St. Petersburg  and take the train to move to Tallinn,do I need passport?

Comment: If you are a Greek citizen you will need passport + visa to enter Russia.

Comment: Even for one day?

Comment: @yannishristofakis Yes.  If you have to clear border control you will need a visa and for a 15 hour stay you're likely to have to do that.  Unless you're planning to stay 15+ hours in the terminal.